# How to close popup window in Foundation Apps

Tags: jquery, popup, zurb-foundation

used for dialog with text popup window, just do not know how it another click anywhere in the document to close. I use Foundation Apps

Source:

```
<i class="icon-help" zf-popup-toggle="popup"></i>
        <zf-popup id="popup" class="padding">
            text ....
        </zf-popup>
```

It is used, for example, some calls via jqueryIt is used, for example, some calls via jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html does your popup have a close button?

Comment: Hi  Tomas May be this link will help you out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421266/adding-logic-on-the-cancel-ok-modal-popup-window-click-foundation-5-modal

Comment: my problem is not  a modal popup window but here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/popup

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the element via jQuery or Vanilla JavaScript, and then remove the class which sets the PopUp to display: true.

Here via AngularJS:

```
angular.element('#popup')[0].classList.remove('tether-enabled');
```

Or via jQuery:

```
$('#popup')[0].classList.remove('tether-enabled');
```

Call this line maybe on body.click or whenever you feel the need.